# AWS CLI --output text is Horizontal instead of Vertical

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running the following command to output to text, but the output is Horizontal. Is there a way to make this output Vertical, where one id per line? I have done this for describing instances which worked fine, I am not sure what's different in this case. My reason is that it is easier to work with in my case. If possible of course.

The `table` and `JSON` outputs are vertical but not `text`. Was curious why is this.

`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces –query 'NetworkInterfaces[].NetworkInterfaceId' --filters "Name=status, Values=available" --output text`

CURRENT OUTPUT:

---

```
eni-1   eni-2   eni-3
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT:

---

```
   eni-1
   eni-2
   eni-3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My query was wrong. I found the issue. Need to enclose it in [] brackets.

`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].[NetworkInterfaceId]' --filters "Name=status, Values=available" --
output text`